# Counting Lines and Conics on a Surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In fact I am trying to find the conditions on curves to be embedded in surfaces (non ruled). Apart from reading the books by Mumford and Kollar I found the following paper useful.

http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~prims/pdf/45-3/45-3-25.pdf

The paper is well written so I don't think I need to write the techniques of this paper. 
Now I am looking for references that describe other kind of techniques available in this area.

Thanks.

Comment: Has the paper actually been published? Google only seems to know about the 2009 preprint you mention.

Comment: Its been published.

Comment: @Igor: that's not a preprint, it's the published version. See http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~prims/list.html

Comment: @Algebraic geometer: You probably have something in mind. Why not ask the real question you are interested in?

Comment: Oops: reading comprehension issues...

Comment: I certainly agree with @Sandor re asking the real question.

Comment: @S'andor -- This is fun!  Do you know the question the OP is interested in?  Are you willing to share with the rest of the class?

Comment: Since you are asking people to do something for you, it might be nice to "pre-reciprocate" by putting in some effort, and briefly describing some of the techniques in that paper.

Comment: @S. Carnahan: I am sorry but I don't consider my writing abilities better than Yoichi Miyaoka, and I don't want to type most of the same paper here again. One way of putting my query is as follows: What are the techniques known related to conics (lines etc ) on an irreducible non-singular surface (non-ruled)? For example, simply, consider the case of number of conics on on a quintic surface?(the max you can get is 4 conics on a quintic surface, you can get 5 conics but then the surface is reducible).

Comment: @Algebraic geometer: There is an upper bound on the number of lines on a smooth degree $d$ surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$, namely $11d^2-28d+12$.  This is the correct order of magnitude, as the Fermat surface contains $3d^2$ lines.  You might want to look at my appendix to the following article http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505186.